# Build Tensorflow Error "Cannot find bazel. Please install bazel"

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, bazel

I want to build tensorflow, I download the file from
"git clone [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git"](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git%22)
I build model using tensorflow-gpu version is 1.14.0 and I use conda to install bazel using command
"conda install -c conda-forge bazel=0.24.1"
However when I run "python ./configure.py" in tensorflow , I got this error
Cannot find bazel. Please install bazel
So, I try "bazel test", and I work fine

Try installing bazel from https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-windows.html
still not work, can someone help please

python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Have you inserted the path to bazel in ~/.bashrc? Maybe you should add it so that tensorflow can find it:

```
echo "PATH=<path>/<to>/<bazel>/output:\$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
```